# With Gtk3, how can I wait for user input in a secondary thread?

Tags: c, multithreading, gtk3

I've an issue with multithreading on gtk3 (C language).

I'm implementing a turn-by-turn game, with one human and several bots.
There is a loop (which is a thread) where bots play one by one, until it's the human's turn.
Then, the loop stops and waits for a correct input from the human (ie from a callback in the main loop).
But when the loop stops, it freezes the main loop to : no displaying, and no callbacks.
If I don't call my own loop before the main loop, the main loop works fine.

Here is the loop and the callback.

```
static Player* human ;
static GCond data_cond ;
static GMutex data_mutex ;

void my_loop(Player** players, int how_many_players) {

  for(int i = 0 ; ; i++) {

    if (*(players + i) != human)
      /* a bot's turn */
    else {
      g_mutex_lock(&data_mutex) ;
      g_cond_wait(&data_cond, &data_mutex) ;
      g_mutex_unlock(&data_mutex) ;
    }
    if (i == how_many_players)
      i = 0 ;
  }
}

gboolean cb_human_input (GtkWidget *event_box,
                         GdkEvent  *event,
                         gpointer data) {
  if (right_input(event_box, event, data)) {
    do_input (event_box, event, data) ;  
    g_cond_signal(&data_cond) ;
    return TRUE ;
  }
  else
    return FALSE ;
}
```

And here is how I call the loop in main.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  gtk_init(&argc,&argv);

  /* Initializations and signals-connecting.
     ...
  */

  // Here I run my loop ; if I don't, the main loop works fine
  gdk_threads_add_idle(my_loop, joueurs) ;

  gtk_main();
}
```

Comment: If this was the answer, you can also post it as such. Self-answering is suggested if you found the answer or an answer to your question. Welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
GThread *g_thread_new (const gchar *name,
          GThreadFunc func,
          gpointer data);
```

instead of:

```
guint gdk_threads_add_idle (GSourceFunc function,
          gpointer data);
```